# Session timeout web.xml inactivity

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF 2.0 , Primefaces 5.3 and Webspehere server. Currently I have set 15 min session timeout in web.xml.

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Application logs out after 15 minutes of idle time which is ok , but it also logs out when user types in some text box for say 15 minutes. Does it mean that if there is no hit to the server ( user typing something without submitting form) , it is considered as inactivity? If so, how to overcome that ?

Comment: First rethink if you timeout is not to short. If users work like this it most likely is. And if you implement 'ajax' then you'll get way more interaction with the server. But if all this is not sufficient (I doubt it is, implement some mechanism like this:

Comment: By making sure that if there **is** activity, it is (periodically) send to the server... First start by defining what 'activity' is. Mousemovement? Clicking somewhere? Entering text? This is all client-side html/javascript. Then send the 'activity' signal to the server (e.g. via a `p:remoteCommand`) and only repeat that after a certain timeout (so not every activity is continuously send to the server. This is btw all generic and not sort of jsf/primefaces related.

Comment: Activity here is entering text in inputTextarea. How do we send the signal to the server?

Comment: I mentioned that in my previous comment